# Adding Existing Files To Different Visual Studio 2010 Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-organization

It is possible to add files to a visual studio project that is located in a different directory however keep the files in those directories and update those file when you update the file in the project? When I add existing files to a project, all it does is copy them to the project and then update the copied files, not the original files. Is there any way to get it to work the other way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should add them as a link/shortcut

Right-click the project, select Add > Existing Item, and in the dialog, "Add" drop down, select "Add As Link".

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Right lick the solution Explorer and
   select Add | Existing item...
3. Select the file and question,  but
   in the "Add" drop down select Add as
   Link.

Alternatively I would suggest creating a class library project that you share in both solutions, this might benefit you in the future.