# changing silverlight class library to wpf class library

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I currently have a library which was created in a silverlight application for its use. But Now we are switching over to WPF. So i don't know how would i convert the library to a wpf library. Would i just have to copy all the file in a new project(wpf class library)

[image]

As you can see when i reference this silver light library in my wpf project. It gives me a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, you can't use a project compiled to target Silverlight as a reference for a project targeting some other .NET framework family. You will need to compile a separate assembly compatible with the .NET framework family you're using (i.e. a desktop version). This will require the creation of a whole new project (I'm not aware of a practical way to have a single project target both Silverlight and desktop .NET).

Note that the new project can use the same source files as the original Silverlight one. After creating the project (which you should create as an "Empty Project"), you can add the source files from the Silverlight project, by using the "Add Existing..."/"As Link" option for adding items to the project. Adding the source code as links will cause the new project to reference the original .cs files in their current location rather than creating a new copy of them for the new project.

Note also that your Silverlight code may or may not be 100% compatible with the WPF API. You may have to introduce conditional compilation (i.e. use `#if`, and declare appropriate conditional compilation symbols, in the projects' settings "Build" tab) so that you can provide correct code for each platform in each .cs file.

Related topics (there a lot of duplicate questions involving adding existing items as links…though many of these involve multiple solutions, not just adding items to a new project):
[Share c# class source code between several projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666898)
[How do I keep common code shared between projects in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4345780)
[Adding Existing Files To Different Visual Studio 2010 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4880844)
[Is it possible to statically share code between projects in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7664275)
[Updating classes used in multiple projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8239451)
[Make reference to C# code from multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9219555)
[Share .cs file among VS 2010 C# projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15907467)
[How to include source files of one project in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20464342)